Givens rotation for all components
I was wondering why in the QR decomposition algorithm using Givens rotations, we only see it presented or coded with "2d" rotations and not a complete "nd" rotation.
Any matrix $A$ (square or rectangular, here I will consider the square case only for notational convenience) can be decomposed as the product of an orthogonal $Q$ and a (upper) triangular matrix $R$
$$ A = QR $$
There are several algorithms to obtain the matrices $Q$ and $R$, mainly the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, the (successive) Househoulder reflections and the (successive) Givens rotations. They all have pros and cons: the Gram-Schmidt algorithm is the easiest to explain but is unstable (it can be partially stabilized), the Householder reflections are the to-go algorithm for dense matrices, the Givens rotations are less efficient than the Householder reflections but can be strongly optimized for sparse matrices.
Givens rotations are always described as "2d" rotations extended as the identity in the $n-2$ remaining dimensions, but it is possible to define a rotation that transform any non-trivial vector of $\mathbf{R}^n$ in (a multiply of) the first element of the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the following way: let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ be a vector that, for simplicity, is of norm $1$ and let us write it as
$$x = \begin{pmatrix}
a\\ \mathbf{b}
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then the matrix
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
a & \mathbf{b}^T \\
-\mathbf{b} & I_{n-1} + (a-1) \frac{\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T}{\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{b}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
(here $I_{n-1}$ is the identity in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$) is orthogonal (non symmetric) and such that
$$Qx = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix}$$
One can iterate this construction for the successive column vectors as in the Householder algorithm to compute the $QR$ factorisation in $n-1$ steps. For comparison, the Householder matrix, computed for the same vector, is
$$U = I_{n} - 2 \mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^T, \qquad \text{where }\mathbf{v} = \frac{\mathbf{x}\pm\|\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{e}_1}{\|\mathbf{x}\pm\|\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{e}_1\|}$$
(the sign can be chosen to ensure stability).
Why is this version of the Givens rotations never introduced in the books? Is it purely for pedagogical reasons or am I missing something? It does seem to be of the same complexity as the Householder reflections, and it is automatically optimized if the vector $\mathbf{b}$ has many zero elements.
Edit: corrected a formula

So have you examined what happens to the previously-corrected columns when you apply your rotation for the next column to them?

You are right Paul, to complete my question, if you want to adjust the -th column, you can proceed iteratively as in the Householder algorithm: say the $k$-th column is of the form
$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{c} \a\ \mathbf{b} \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, assuming $a^2+|\mathbf{b}|^2 =1$. Then
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{k-1} & 0 & \mathbf{0}^T\
0 & a & \mathbf{b}^T \
\mathbf{0} &-\mathbf{b} & I_{n-k} + (a-1) \frac{\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T}{\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{b}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
